# How can I make Arabic fonts in GIMP work?

Tags: font, arabic

If I select an Arabic font like Kufi (كوفي) and enter text into GIMP 2.8.14 on OS X 10.11, this is the result:

[image: Screenshot of GIMP with broken Arabic]

As you can see, the letters are incorrectly disjointed.

If I right-click on the text and select "From right to left", it makes no difference. In the text tool's options, I can change the language from English to Arabic, but it makes no difference. I can also change the justification to centered or to left-aligned, but it makes no difference.

Some fonts I select do render with the letters connected, but it looks like it's simply using a fallback font.

Answer (score -1):

You better ask Gimp!
Gimp FAQ :  http://www.gimp.org/docs/userfaq.html
Or ask Gimp Support.

Comment: The FAQ doesn't have an answer to this question.